# Color clan tags in BC2?

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2

Is it possible to add color to the clan tags in BC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at present, and to my knowledge it's not planned.

Personally, I certainly wouldn't mind it if it were restricted to clan tags.  Bad Company 2 uses colorization of the name, though, to distinguish between squad/friend/enemy so I can see why some would consider even colorized clan tags to be distracting.

Comment: Thanks.. good to know.  I thought I'd seen is somewhere but I guess it was a different game